# How can I change date format in csv in Python 3

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to Python, and I have a set of data in a CSV file that I would like to change the format from

`'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ'` to `'%m/%d/%Y'`

I'm running Python 3 on Windows. I've searched S.O. (and other sites) several times but none of the examples/solutions seem to actually convert the format of the output. I've read the Python online documentation but was unable to take anything meaningful away from it.

Here's the code I just tried, and it doesn't change the formatting on any of the entries in the column:

```
with open('some_file', 'r') as source:
    with open('some_other_file', 'w') as result:
        writer = csv.writer(result, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(source)
        source.readline()
        for row in reader:
            ts = row[17]
            ts = datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ').strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            if ts != "":
                writer.writerow(row)
source.close()
result.close()
```

I get no errors, but I get no change in the format of the timestamp either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a date `x`:

```
x = "2017-07-01T15:55Z"
```

You can convert it into a `datetime.datetime` with your formate `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ`:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ')
```

Then format it:

```
d.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

You'll get:

```
'07/01/2017'
```

The complete code is:

```
from datetime import datetime
x = "2017-07-01T15:55Z"
x = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ').strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

======= EDIT =======

For your follow up question:
you need to change `row` after formatting `ts`:

```
ts = row[17]
ts = datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ').strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
if ts != "":
    row[17] = ts # this is what you miss
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I tried your example with no results. I am doing something wrong, but I do not know what (see code snippet above).

Comment: @BrianHowe you changed `ts` but not `row`. See my answer. Hope it works now.

Comment: Thank you. That one line was what was missing. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a string in your CSV file that looks like `'2017-08-10T20:47Z'`. You should convert this to a `datetime.datetime` instance with

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime('2017-08-10T20:47Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ')
```

This will give you a `datetime.datetime` object:  `datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 10, 20, 47)`. You can then reformat it as required with

```
dts = dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

giving the result `'08/10/2017'` in `dts` to write to your updated CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('some_file.csv', 'r') as source:
    with open('some_other_file.csv', 'w') as result:
        writer = csv.writer(result, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(source)
        source.readline()
        for row in reader:
            ts = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%y %H:%M').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00")
            print(ts)
            row[0]=ts
            if ts != "":
                writer.writerow(row)
source.close()
result.close()
```